# Google Cloud App Engine redirect all /*.html endings to /?

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, redirect, url-rewriting, app.yaml

I have a lot of backlinks on the internet containing a .html ending. E.g. https://mywebsite.de/blog.html
But all my sites are served as https://mywebsite.de/blog in the meanwhile.
I use a Flask backend and found no solution to redirect those .html endings to /.
Is there a possibility to use the app.yaml configuration file for that?
Maybe something like:

```
handlers:
- url: /*.html
{define here the redirect}
```

I found nothing helpful in the documentation with regards to it. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref?hl=de#handlers_element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do this within Flask.  I see two main options.

(1) You could create Flask route that matches using a regular expression.  You then match all routes ending in `.html` and do the redirect.

(2) Use `@app.before_request` on a function, check to see if `request.url` ends in `.html` and then redirect.

Note that `redirect` in Flask is a 302 by default and you probably want to specify a 301 redirect.

Answer (score 0):

As gaefan suggested I solved the issue with Flask itself. My solution looks like the following:

```
@app.route('/blog/<slug>.html')
def html_redirect(slug):
    return redirect(f"https://mywebsite.de/blog/{slug}" ,code=301)
```

Attention: this only redirect for subsites of /blog. Not just anything containing a ".html" ending.